# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 1: Element; 2: Element; 3: Element; }'. TS7053

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For example, suppose you have a form that contains a select box, and you want to change the component to be displayed depending on the value of the select box.

```
　　　<form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
      <label>
        Type:
        <select value={type} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}>
          <option></option>
          <option value={1}>First</option>
          <option value={2}>Second</option>
          <option value={3}>Third</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <SecondElement type={type} />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Then, I want to switch the element to be displayed based on the value passed as the SecondElement property above.

```
export default function SecondElement({ type }: any) {
  return (
    <>
      {
        {
          1: <FirstElem />,
          2: <SecondElem />,
          3: <ThirdElem />,
        }[type]
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

And I got back the error I mentioned in the title which is :

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 1: Element; 2: Element; 3: Element; }'.  TS7053
```

Still, I have no idea how to fix this issue so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: `type` comes from an object of type `any` so `type` itself can be of any type (it could even be of type `Boat`) so you can't really use that to index an object which can be indexed by numbers (in this case) or numbers/strings/symbols in general. You need to be more specific in your types

Answer (score 1):

You were close. All you have to do is to restrict the type of the argument type (the key). In your case, it has to be a number as the keys you use in your examples are all numbers.

```js
export default function SecondElement( { type } : { type: number } ) {
  return (
    <>
      {
        {
          1: <FirstElem />,
          2: <SecondElem />,
          3: <ThirdElem />,
        }[type]
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

A more advanced version is one that supports both number and string keys. The options parameter is your object with the different choices.

```js
export default function SecondElement<T extends string|number>( { type } : { type: T }, options : any ) {
    return options[type]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jack-wester. As for the advanced version, how to define `options`  in this case?

Comment: i.e) How to return selected Element object?